# CSS dashed text situation

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I have this modified codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPPgoY (the original version was made by Lucas Bebber) and I was trying to make it work in wordpress using the custom `css` fields but I think that something is missing it doesn't work.

1)Should I have to use a `css3` plugin to import an external file or something? the first `css` line makes me think of that.

2)If the above mentioned point is it too much, is there any possibility to modify the code in order to be used without animation in `css` custom field in wordpress?

HTML

```
<div data-text="a" class="dashed-shadow">a</div> 
<div class="dashed-shadow">a</div>
```

css

```
@import "compass/css3";

//Variables here:
//(alongside with commented suggestions)
$foreground-color:orange;//black;
$background-color:white;//white
$shadow-color:gray;//$foreground-color;
$distance:18px;
$cut-distance:3px;//$distance/4;
$strips-size:6px; //10px nice values 4px,3px
$strips-ratio:50%;//70%
$strips-angle:45deg;//90deg;

//cray stuff yo. be sure to try (if you please)
$animate:false;//true
$fixed:false;//true

body{
  font-family: 'arial black';
  font-size:895pt;
  background-color:$background-color;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:1em;
  padding-top:5px;
}
.dashed-shadow{
  position:relative;
  top:$distance;
  left:$distance;
  display:inline-block;
  color:$shadow-color;
}
@keyframes dash-animation{
  0% {background-position:0 0};
  100% {background-position:100% 0};
}
.dashed-shadow:before{
  content:" ";
  display:block;

  position:absolute;
  $bleeding-horizontal:0px;
  $bleeding-vertical:0px;
  top:350px;
  left:-$bleeding-vertical - $distance;
  bottom:-$bleeding-horizontal + $distance;
  right:-$bleeding-horizontal + $distance;
  z-index:1;
  $color:$background-color;
  $size:$strips-ratio/2;
  $halfSize:$size/2;
  $p1:$halfSize;
  $p2:50%-$halfSize;
  $p3:50%+$halfSize;
  $p4:100%-$halfSize;
  $transparent:transparentize($color,1);
  @include background-image(linear-gradient($strips-angle,$color $p1, $transparent $p1, $transparent $p2,$color $p2, $color $p3, $transparent $p3, $transparent $p4, $color $p4));
  background-size:$strips-size $strips-size;
  @if($animate){
    animation:dash-animation 30s infinite linear; 
  }
  @if($fixed){
    background-attachment:fixed;
  }
}
.dashed-shadow:hover:before{
  animation:dash-animation 10s infinite linear;
}

.dashed-shadow:after{
  z-index:2;
  content:attr(data-text);
  position:absolute;
  left:-$distance;
  top:-$distance;
  color:$foreground-color;
  text-shadow:$cut-distance $cut-distance $background-color;
}
```

Comment: The CSS @import directive pulls in an outside css file, so you are certainly needing to supply that file for the css to work as expected...

Comment: thank you for your feed-back, good to know as a starting point, and that file should be? LE: I've found [this](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/) could be a part of the answer I'll keep searching.

Comment: no idea other than what you posted: `compass/css3`

Comment: You need to use SASS [http://sass-lang.com/] with Compass [http://compass-style.org/] to compile that to CSS. You could also probably derive the CSS from the Codepen through dev tools.

Comment: I've visited that links, but as soon as I've started to read, I've found myself alone, deeper in "the dark" :) dev tools could help if we don't have the `css` code am I right? In my case, I already have it but only in this animated version that require compass. I dont see how dev tools  could help me to extract the static version ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the point number 1); you do not need a plugin of any kind to use the css bits from codepen. Click on the little gear next to css text in the css window header and then click on the "analyze CSS" (via CSS Lint). It will provide you with standalone code that you can just copy/paste or adjust to the existing css code on your site.

Comment: Thank you, In other words if I convert the code into pure css, without using `compass/sass` will be enough to see the animation too? In my case everything is still http://goo.gl/F5euJr

Comment: You will need to select the "Autoprefixer" option in the same menu so once you compile or export the css it will add property definitions for different browsers. In your case it will provide "-webkit-keyframes dash-animation" property for chrome. I think in other browsers it already works fine.